# Make background darker when sidebar is open in React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, sidebar

I'm trying to customize a sidebar using [react-pro-sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar) with React + Typescript.
The sidebar looks fine but I cannot make the other part of the screen darker colored when the sidebar is opened.

Also, I would like to make the button that opens/closes the sidebar as a separate button. Is it possible in this case?

Here is a working sandbox of my code so far:  https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lichterman-qqpp5?file=/src/App.tsx

And the same code put here:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from "react-pro-sidebar";

import "react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css";
export interface SidebarProps {
  onChange?: (event: React.MouseEvent, isChecked?: boolean) => void;
  isCheckedInitial: boolean;
}

export function Sidebar({ onChange, isCheckedInitial, ...rest }: SidebarProps) {
  const [isChecked, setCheckedState] = useState(isCheckedInitial);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckedState(isCheckedInitial);
  }, [isCheckedInitial]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    setCheckedState(!isChecked);
    onChange && onChange(event, isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <ProSidebar collapsed={isChecked}>
      <Menu iconShape="square">
        <MenuItem onClick={handleChange}>click </MenuItem>
        <SubMenu title="Top 1">
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="Top 2">
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
        </SubMenu>
        <SubMenu title="Top 3">
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Sub menu</MenuItem>
        </SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    </ProSidebar>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a `fixed` positioned `div` for that. I edited your example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-babycat-cg872

I added a `button` and an overlay `div` to the sidebar:

```
<button onClick={handleChange}>click me</button>
// <ProSidebar ...
<div
    className={`overlay ${!isChecked ? 'visible' : ''}`}
    onClick={handleChange}
/>
```

and added some css:

```
button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
}

.overlay.visible {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it solves the problem with the darker background. related to the separate button, it isn't what is expected, is it possible to hide all the sidebar when the button is set on 'closed'? Something like this example (https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/y3O1) but with the button being fixed above it and visible all the time.

Comment: The sidebar component supports a `collapsedWidth` property. I updated the codesandbox link accordingly so that the sidebar collapses down to `0px`.